# Chrome Extensions: Show modified background.html

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an array of data that I want to show to the user of the extension. I thought of manipulating the background page and populating it with data then showing it to the user via: `chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL('background.html')}`

However, this opens a brand new background.html page that is not manipulated and, further more, within a totally different context than the original background.html...

[image]

i.e I don't have access in that new page to my array that I want to show to the user.

I also tried with a different page than background.html -> results.html...I get its url then send it a message with the array that I want to show to the user:

`chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL('results.html')},function(tab){
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,{'personsarray':persons});
});`

Then in results.js:

`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(request);
               //other operations
});`

but it seems the message is not being sent! can't find anything in the console!

Questions:

1. Is it possible to show data to user using the background.html page?
2. What are the appropriate ways to show data to the user in chrome extensions?
3. Why am I not receiving the message sent from background.js to results.js?

Answer (score 0):

Background pages have unrestricted access to each other. When you created the results.html the next appropriate step would have been to call chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage() from results.html 's javascript page to get the background page window object. That object will contain all of the data and objects in background.html.